# Unable to understand One-Way Binding in Angular2

Tags: angular

As per [Binding Documentation of Angular2](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)
`[target]="expression"`  will create One-way Binding from data source to view target.
But when I do this `target="HELLO WORLD"`, it works fine as well. Should not the second command give me an error instead??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target="HELLO WORLD"` is giving to `target` the value of the `HELLO WORLD` string, while `[target]="expression"` is giving `target` the value of the `expression` variable.

You could also do `[target]="'HELLO WORLD'"` and that would be the same as `target="HELLO WORLD"`

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different types of Data Binding methods provided by AngularJS

```
[target] = 'expression'
```

is a type of Property Binding. and

```
target = 'expression'
```

is an example of String Data Binding.

Both will work in this scenario. You can read more about them to understand their different use cases.

This article can help you [Angular 4 Data Bindings](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/58/Angular-4-Property-Binding-Tutorial)